# Codeigniter nested Helpers?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, helper

I am looking to write a few simple Helpers that can deal with deleting files for example.

But lets say I have a Helper, deleteAllFiles(), which, given a valid path, will delete all files and if the path is a directory, it will delete that too.

I have a small recursive function that can do this, which I'd like to call via the deleteAllFiles() Helper.

How can I call another function within the same Helper file, and is this the correct way to go about this?

There may be other Helpers defined in this file, which may also use the recursive delete function, as to not duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A helper file may contain multiple functions. Examine the file `system/helpers/url_helper.php` for an example. So bundling a related set of helper functions in the same file clearly has a precedent.

Once a helper is loaded you’ll call its functions the way you would any standard PHP function. (Take good old `base_url()` for example.) Calling one helper function from another helper function should not present any problems.

Whether these functions should be procedural or in an object-oriented format (in a class) is a matter of opinion.

Comment: What about calling a helper function form within the same helper file? Do I need to use the $ci = &get_instance() to call $ci->another_helper_function()? Or can I just do another_helper_function() in the same helper?

Comment: @MrPablo, Intended to edit my answer in reply to  your comment above but accidentally edited your question instead. Check it out.

Comment: Can't see any edits? Either way, thanks. I got it working after taking a quick peak at the URL helper :)